# read a tabular dataset from a text file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have many text files with the following format,

```
%header
%header
table
.
.
.
another table
.
.
.
```

If I didn't have the second table, I could use a simple commnad to read the file such as :

```
numpy.loadtxt(file_name, skiprows=2, dtype=float, usecols={0, 1})
```

is there an easy way to read the first table without having to read the files line by line, something like `numpy.loadtxt`

Comment: I understand `.` to be a placeholder for actual data, but is `%header` the actual text in the file?  If not, does the header provide information about the following tables?  Does the header specify the number of rows in the tables?  Please give a small example of an *actual* file.

Comment: the dots are the data in the table, and yes, I can parse the headers to find the size of the tables.

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` read the file line by line; they just hide the details. Both also accept input from any thing that will feed it lines - such as list of lines, or file reader that selects the lines to pass on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) and set `max_rows` according to info from the header.

As an example, I created the following data file:

```
# nrows=10
# nrows=15
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
.
.
.
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
.
.
.
```

The the following oversimplified code could read the two tables from the file (of course you can enhance the code to meet your needs):

```
f = open('filename.txt')
# read header and find the number of rows to read for each table:
p = f.tell()
l = f.readline()
tabrows = []
while l.strip().startswith('#'):
    if 'nrows' in l:
        tabrows.append(int(l.split('=')[1]))
    p = f.tell()
    l = f.readline()
f.seek(p)
# read all tables assuming each table is followed by three lines with a dot:
import numpy as np
tables = []
skipdots = 0
ndotsafter = 3
for nrows in tabrows:
    tables.append(np.genfromtxt(f, skip_header=skipdots, max_rows=nrows))
    skipdots = ndotsafter
f.close()
```